# Structured debug log

Tags: debugging, logging

I am writing a complex application (a compiler analysis). To debug it I need to examine the application's execution trace to determine how its values and data structures evolve during its execution. It is quite common for me to generate megabytes of text output for a single run and sifting my way through all that is very labor-intensive. To help me manage these logs I've written my own library that formats them in HTML and makes it easy to color text from different code regions and indent code in called functions. An example of the output is [here](http://www.anony.ws/i/2013/05/31/zTdHL.png).

My question is: is there any better solution than my own home-spun library? I need some way to emit debug logs that may include arbitrary text and images and visually structure them and if possible, index them so that I can easily find the region of the output I'm most interested. Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: I did research in this area ~10 years ago. What you have is as good as anything I have seen; I especially like the HTML version. My suggestion is to trial different ways of characterizing each trace. One might be to produce a raster image where each row is a bar representing the depth of the call graph. A second dimension could be represented by color, say to show dynamic memory use. But only you know what you are interested in! As you refine your visualizations you will need to be able to reprocess your old logs to produce the new outputs. Post a link to your paper when it's written :-)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless you didn't mentioned a language applied, I'd like to propose apache Log4XXX family: http://logging.apache.org/

It offers customizable details level as well as tag-driven loggers. GUI tool (chainsaw) can be combined with "old good" GREP approach (so you see only what you're interested in at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Colorizing, search and filtering using an expression syntax is available in the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw.  The expression syntax also supports regular expressions (using the 'like' keyword).

Chainsaw can parse any regular text log file, not just log files generated by log4j.

The latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw is available here:
http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

The File, load Chainsaw configuration menu item is where you define the 'format' and location of the log file you want to process, and the expression syntax can be found in the tutorial, available from the help menu.

Feel free to email the log4j users list if you have additional questions.

Comment: any chance you can write a blog or gist/ sample how to use chaing saw to get log events from a log file programmatically (do not need any GUI) just the log fields in a hash map or Pojo ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I created a framework that might help you, https://github.com/pablito900/VisualLogs